Changing Blazor's behavior when checking for changed parameters
In this previous question: A group of parameter types that Blazor explicitly checks it is explained which types Blazor will detect diffs for, and which types it will assume are changed:

If StateHasChanged is called in a parent component, the Blazor
framework rerenders child components if their parameters might have
changed:

For a group of parameter types that Blazor explicitly checks, Blazor rerenders a child component if it detects that any of the parameters
have changed.
For unchecked parameter types, Blazor rerenders the child component regardless of whether or not the parameters have changed. Child
content falls into this category of parameter types because child
content is of type RenderFragment, which is a delegate that refers to
other mutable objects.


However, I would like to be able to control the behavior so that I can explicitly check more types that I have control over.  From what I can tell,  the code that actually performs the check inside Blazor is all internal and so not amenable to changing. However, using a custom component it seems like we might be able to do a second pass through all the parameters in SetParametersAsync and return early if there are no changes according to our custom change detection logic.
Are there existing examples of code implementing this behavior?  How to we make things have reasonable performance if we are using reflection to check all the parameter values?

How are you going to define the types?  What types did you have in mind?

I was thinking of some parameters being checked for equality by reference, some being checked by .Equals, and some assuming that they are never changed.  I am experimenting with using custom attributes to specify which parameters get treated which way.

The decision on calling SetParametersAsync is made by the Renderer based on the checks referenced in the question.  We have no control over that process.
What we can do is a make a more informed decision on whether a render is required within SetParametersAsync and abort where necessary.
In the ComponentBase version of SetParametersAsync, the parameters are set like this in the first line of the method.  This uses a lot of reflection and is relatively expensive.
parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);

Here's a demo component that manually sets the value instead.
<h3>TestControl</h3>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-1 p-2">
    <pre>@this.Data.Value</pre>
</div>

@{
    Console.WriteLine("TestControl Rendered"); 
}

@code {
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public Data Data { get; set; } = new();

    public async override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        bool somethingChanged = false;

        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            switch (parameter.Name)
            {
                case nameof(Data):
                    var value = (Data)parameter.Value;
                    if (value != this.Data)
                    {
                        this.Data = value;
                        somethingChanged = true;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException($"Unknown parameter: {parameter.Name}");
            }
        }

        // Abort render if nothing has changed
        if (!somethingChanged)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nothing has changed.  Abort update");
            return;
        }

        // call the base to render the component if there's mutation
        await base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }
}

Data is a simple record.  You have to create a new instance to mutate it.
public record Data()
{
    public string? Value { get; init; }
}

Be careful with objects, you're passing a reference, so checking
if (Data == data)

Will simply check the references.
Here's my Demo page:
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<TestControl Data="_data" />

<div class="m-2">
   <button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="() => this.OnClicked(false)">Just a Click</button>
   <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="() => this.OnClicked(true)">Update Data</button>
</div>

@code {
   private Data _data = new();

   private Task OnClicked(bool reset)
   {
       if(reset)
           _data = _data with { Value = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() };

       return Task.CompletedTask;
   }
}

And what you'll see logged is:
=> lots of "Just a Click" clicks
Nothing has changed.  Abort update
Nothing has changed.  Abort update
Nothing has changed.  Abort update
Nothing has changed.  Abort update
Nothing has changed.  Abort update
=> 3 "Update Data" clicks
TestControl Rendered
TestControl Rendered
TestControl Rendered
=> lots more "Just a Click" clicks
Nothing has changed.  Abort update
Nothing has changed.  Abort update
Nothing has changed.  Abort update
Nothing has changed.  Abort update
=> a "Update Data" click
TestControl Rendered

There a Microsoft article on the subject here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/performance?view=aspnetcore-8.0#implement-setparametersasync-manually.

Thanks for this!  It seems like we might be able to use code generation to avoid having to write out all this boilerplate for each type.

Yes, a combination of custom attributes and code generation should work.  You just need to be careful as the Razor Compiler is doing a similar thing!

Yes, it surprises me that they don't do something like this in the first place! I posted the solution I ended up with. Thanks again for the guidance.

I worked out the following implementation that allows fine grained control over the way parameter changes are detected.
First, I defined these attributes that you can attach to your Blazor component parameters:
// For Blazor parameters which *cannot* change. If the parameter is changed despite this attribute, OnParametersSetAsync
// will not be called.
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class FixedParameterAttribute : Attribute;

// For Blazor parameters which should be compared using reference equality. If the parameter is the same object,
// OnParametersSetAsync will not be called.
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class CheckReferenceParameterAttribute : Attribute;

// For Blazor parameters which should be compared using .Equals(). If the parameter is equal, OnParametersSetAsync
//  will not be called.
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class CheckEqualityParameterAttribute : Attribute;

Then inside my Base component:
public class BaseComponent : IComponent, IHandleEvent, IHandleAfterRender
{
  
  // .... The rest of the implementation is copied from ComponentBase or your favorite custom Component base class ...

[SuppressMessage("Major Code Smell",
        "S3011:Reflection should not be used to increase accessibility of classes, methods, or fields")]
    public virtual async Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        bool anyChanged = false;

        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            var propertyMetadata = PropertyCache.GetOrAdd((GetType(), parameter.Name), key =>
            {
                var propInfo = key.Item1.GetProperty(key.Item2,
                    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                return new PropertyMetadata(key.Item1, propInfo!);
            });

            object? newValue = (object?)parameter.Value;
            object? oldValue = (object?)propertyMetadata.GetValue(this);

            if (oldValue == null && newValue == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (propertyMetadata.IsFixed)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (propertyMetadata.IsCheckReference)
            {
                if (!ReferenceEquals(oldValue, newValue))
                {
                    anyChanged = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if (propertyMetadata.IsCheckEquality)
            {
                if (!Equals(oldValue, newValue))
                {
                    anyChanged = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                anyChanged = true;
            }
        }

        if (!anyChanged && _initialized)
        {
            return;
        }

        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
        if (!_initialized)
        {
            _initialized = true;
            await RunInitAndSetParametersAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            await CallOnParametersSetAsync();
        }
    }

    private class PropertyMetadata
    {
        public bool IsFixed { get; }
        public bool IsCheckReference { get; }
        public bool IsCheckEquality { get; }
        public Func<object, object> GetValue { get; }

        public PropertyMetadata(Type targetType, PropertyInfo property)
        {
            IsFixed = property.IsDefined(typeof(FixedParameterAttribute));
            IsCheckReference = property.IsDefined(typeof(CheckReferenceParameterAttribute));
            IsCheckEquality = property.IsDefined(typeof(CheckEqualityParameterAttribute)) || IsKnownImmutableType(property.PropertyType);

            GetValue = CreateGetDelegate(targetType, property);
        }

        private static Func<object, object> CreateGetDelegate(Type targetType, PropertyInfo property)
        {
            var instance = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "instance");
            var convertInstance = Expression.Convert(instance, targetType);
            var propertyAccess = Expression.Property(convertInstance, property);
            var convertPropertyAccess = Expression.Convert(propertyAccess, typeof(object));

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(convertPropertyAccess, instance).Compile();
        }

        // See ChangeDetection.cs in Blazor.
        private static bool IsKnownImmutableType(Type type)
            => Type.GetTypeCode(type) != TypeCode.Object
               || type == typeof(Guid);
    }
}

When using it, you can just mark the parameters like:
@code {

    [Parameter, FixedParameter]
    public MyObject Foo {get; set;}
}

And because it is marked with the FixedParameter attribute, it will never be detected as a change.  If I used CheckReferenceParameter then it would just check whether the reference has changed to do change detection.
The I think there still could be some room for improvement using compile time code generation to get better performance, but it's already using compiled expressions which are cached to get much better performance than raw reflection.

This is a great idea and a great start! This solves a lot of problems with complex component parameters that trigger OnParameterSet unnecessarily. Would love to see this expanded into a full package!

I solved this for a Marquee component I've created. I needed the component widths to be rechecked if the supplied text changed.

create a private boolean variable initialised as false.
In OnInitialized create a copy of the parameter.
In OnAfterRender check if this variable is set to true

if so then call any functions required
set the variable to false


In OnParametersSet check if the required parameter has changed compared to the stored copy.

if so then update the stored copy

set the variable to true
private string _text = "";
private bool _textChanged = false;
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
...
...
_text = text;
}
protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
if (_textChanged)
{
...
...
_textChanged = false;
}
}
protected override void OnParametersSet()
{
if (text != _text)
{
_text = text;
_textChanged = true;
}
}




